# Dataplotly Background Grid

Tags: qgis, dataplotly

[image]Correct me if I am wrong but did we not used to be able to see the background grid and customize the color of it etc. with DATAPLOTLY?
I cannot see where to edit/show that now!

Comment: new release is coming soon! https://github.com/ghtmtt/DataPlotly/pull/259